# Powershell 5.1 Powershell Remoting login script?

Tags: powershell

Is there a mechanism equivalent to a ssh login script that can be triggered when one enters into a remote PSSession?

It would be nice to create PSDrives, enforce settings, etc. either remotely or interactively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a few scripts in the `$psProfilePath` location to do some similar things, like import a few functions, in local Powershell consoles. I think you should be able to use this for a remote session as well.

For regular Powershell hosts:

```
$psProfilePath\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

For ISE Powershell hosts:

```
$psProfilePath\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```